# Redirect Specman simulator to load files rather than $SPECMAN_PATH

Tags: specman

Is there another way to redirect specman simulator to load files rather than $SPECMAN_PATH ? 
Through irun command maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

irun has an optionflag -snpath which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

irun -snpath /home/projects/...

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Such short answers without any explanations or context are in most cases not very helpful. Your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.